# Google Chrome Starts With Hidden Instances

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash, pandora

Going to post this here - it turns out AskDifferent is ... pretty dead.

So - weird things today.

Because of another issue, I had to close google chrome and restart it. When it restarted, Pandora started playing - however, there is no pandora to be found. No window nor tab.

I thought I'd be able to figure out where or what was going on with the Activity Monitor - but I found very little to indicate which instance (if any at all) was hiding and playing pandora stations. So, my next step was to run ps aux|grep chrome -i with very little helpful information, just a slew of instances. Figured I'd try running ps aux | grep 'pandora' -i which returned nothing at all.

So - I have an invisible pandora tab playing pandora somewhere. Obviously I could try re-starting chrome, but that's not the point. The concern is that this is even happening at all. Is this a flash issue? Do I need to worry about youtube playing via mysterious phantom chrome instances?

If anyone can help me with this, I would be ever so grateful!

Comment: Try using Activity Monitor and sort by CPU%. The pandora process will probably be at the top of the list.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, actually. I guess it doesn't much matter if I kill some random tab - but still it would be nice if there was a way to truly verify which instance was tied to Pandora. Maybe a process tree?

Comment: Did you see the Chrome Task Manager (Menu -> View Background Pages)?